# Mocking select all query from a SQL Server Database using Moq

Tags: c#, sql-server, mocking, nunit, moq

I am new to mocking with Moq and I am currently learning with a simple database that I created.

So far what I have done is I have successfully stub the database connection and did a test on my insert to database method by following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795338/mocking-insert-query-to-a-mysql-database-using-moq) and I am currently trying to do a unit test on a method that fetches everything from a database table. I received the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

when I ran the test. Since the code was not connected to the database so no data was fetched so I assume that is the reason why I got the error.

Any ideas on how to approach and do a unit test on the select all method?

**My select all method:**

```
public string GetAll()
{
    using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            string result = string.Format("{0,-5} {1,-15} {2,-15} \n", "ID", "BurgersLeft", "BurgersSold");
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MySales";
                SqlDataReader data =  command.ExecuteReader() as SqlDataReader;
                
                while (data.Read())
                {
                    string firstCell = data[0].ToString();
                    string secondCell = data[1].ToString();
                    string thirdCell = data[1].ToString();

                    result += string.Format("{0,-5} {1,-15} {2,-15} \n", firstCell, secondCell, thirdCell);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
         }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My Unit Test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    db obj = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var mock = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
        var command = mock.OneOf<IDbCommand>();
        var connection = mock.OneOf<IDbConnection>(_ => _.CreateCommand() == command);
        var factory = mock.OneOf<IDbConnectionFactory>(_ => _.CreateConnection() == connection);

        obj = new db(factory);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        obj = null;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Insert_Test()
    {
        bool result = obj.Insert(3,5,6);
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(true));
    }


    [Test]
    public void GetAll_Test()
    {
        string result = obj.GetAll();
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: `command.ExecuteReader() as SqlDataReader` will probably return null if command isn't an SqlCommand object.

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception on? Also it would be helpful if you could post more of the class which you are testing - specifically the constructor as that may help to narrow down the issue.