# How to write unit test with asp.net core call stored procedure?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a connection from asp.net core with mysql database in order to create api.
And I have create some method to verify something, but I don't know how to write a unit with below method.

Please help explain and give some examples.

Thank any ways.

```
protected virtual bool IsUserPermission(Query query, string scope, string sessionID, string clientID, string connStrTransactions)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scope))
            {
                JObject res = GetRsp(query, sessionID, clientID);

                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStrTransactions))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("AuthUserPermission", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        MySqlParameter rv = new MySqlParameter("value", MySqlDbType.Text);
                        rv.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(rv);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUserId", (res["UserId"]));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pModule", (res["Module"]));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pOperation", (res["Operation"]));
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        var result = cmd.Parameters["value"].Value;
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: This code is tightly coupled to implementation concerns which make testing it in isolation difficult. The shown code would only be able to be tested via integration testing with a connection to actual database.

Comment: Thank @Nkosi Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Check the answer I gave here about abstracting the dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799362/5233410

Comment: I go an error:   Message: 
The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: Student student